# Graybar below each window in windows 10

Tags: windows-10

Recently in Windows 10, sometimes when I maximize the windows, a gray bar appears at the top of the screen. When I click on the graybar, it actualy select the icons from desktop.

It appears not only in  the main Windows' windows but also on the other applications such as Virtualbox

Any idea how to fix it? I add some screenshots to clarify the issue:

[image]

Comment: Try a different, perhaps plainer, Windows Theme (Settings, Personalization), restart and check

Comment: I changed the resolution and reset back my main resolution and it disappeared. but I am sure it will back again soon :-(